# VLC won't install, says I'm missing libvlccore.so. I have .9 it's looking for .8 What's next?

Tags: apt, vlc

I used to have a working install of vlc on my system.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
```

After a long bout of not being connected to the interwebs, my system fell out of date, when I reconnected to the internet, and tried to update and upgrade, it failed and failed and failed. Finally found that VLC was to blame, or gradio?, but got rid of them, and their sources, and finally got it updated and upgraded using

```
apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing -f -y && reboot
```

^really just truncated example, after trying `--fix-missing` it recommended I `add -f.`

Figured now I would try to get the video player installed again. Yet I run into this error:

```
Setting up libxcb-composite0:amd64 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up vlc (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
    /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen: error while loading shared libraries: libvlccore.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARNING: Regenerating VLC plugin cache failed.
Please run 'vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins' manually.

root@wrench:/home/wrench# vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins

    vlc-cache-gen: command not found

root@wrench:/home/wrench# cd / && ./usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins

    ./usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen: error while loading shared libraries: libvlccore.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

root@wrench:/# locate libvlccore.so

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0
```

So synopsis, what the heck do I do now? Is there a way to downgrade libvlccore.so back to 8? Maybe not due to security implications? Maybe I'm doing something stupid like installing the wrong architecture? I know I messed with the arch to get an package installed when I first set up the box, but was careful to check (I thought) that everything was changed back after the install.  Please help, the family is bored!

Maybe someone knows where to find libvlccore.so.8?

Comment: `libvlccore.so.8` is used on all Ubuntu-provided versions of VLC in 16.04 - 17.10. `libvlccore.so.9` is used in 18.04. Ubuntu does NOT upgrade VLC versions during the life of an LTS (the whole point of LTS is that the versions are *stable*). Therefore, it seems likely that you installed some non-Ubuntu version of VLC. We don't support those. Uninstall it.

Comment: How would I go about finding it, as far as i know, i removed what I had, in an attempt to fix it. `apt-get purge vlc` and all..

EDIT : trying apt-get `autoremove` now.

Comment: Remove all vlc source packages, update your sources & install vlc.. You obviously had used a vlc ppa in the past. To use the repo version this should suffice `sudo apt purge libvlccore9 vlc-data` then `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install vlc`  If still issues then run `apt-cache policy vlc` & post

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libvlccore.so.9 libvlccore.so.8
```

This will create a symlink called `libvlccore.so.8` to the version you have, `libvlccore.so.9`, so programs looking for version *8 will call the newer library. This is not generally good practice, since version 9 is different from 8 and may not work. It can serve as a workaround, though.